# Add suffix to file after upload

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm uploading files and I would like to add a little functionality - if you upload a file with  a name that already exists, add a suffix (number) so you have for example file, file1, file2 etc.

I've read some solutions here and this is what I got so far:

```
$fileTmpLoc =  $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

$upload_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/projektOpole/upload/";

for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {

if (file_exists($upload_dir) && is_writable($upload_dir) && file_exists($upload_dir.$fileName)) {
$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $upload_dir.$fileName.$i);
}
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Could somebody tell me what's wrong with my code? I'm total PHP newbie, so please try to keep it very simple.

Comment: You cannot move a single file 100 times. Can copy, but not move ;)

Comment: Right, I see it now, thnx :)

Answer (score 1):

Try following code.

```
 $fileTmpLoc =  $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
 $fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

get the extension of file

```
 $extension = end(explode('.', $fileName));
```

File name without extension

```
  $filenameWithoutExt = substr($fileName, 0, -(strlen($extension)+1));

   $upload_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/projektOpole/upload/";

   $is_writable = 0;
```

set the flag if dir is writable

```
  if(is_writable($upload_dir)){
     $is_writable = 1;
  }
  if($is_writable){
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
       if (file_exists($upload_dir.$fileName)) {
          $moveResult = copy($upload_dir.$fileName, $upload_dir.$filenameWithoutExt.$i.".".$extension);
       }else{
           $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $upload_dir.$fileName);
       }
     }
   }
```

Comment: It doesn't upload at all now. This line: $filenameWithoutExt = substr($fileName, 0, (strlen($extension)+1);  gives me a syntax error (unexpected ';' ), is there something wrong with it?

Comment: Sorry - it does upload the file now, but still - only once, no new files with new names.

Comment: replace line with thi 
    $filenameWithoutExt = substr($fileName, 0, (strlen($extension)+1));

Comment: Updated the code . and its working . please check :)

Comment: I have checked it and its working, 
copy the whole code again and run.

Comment: Ok, I had an external problem, now it's working, though what it does is it keeps saving the file over and over until it reaches 100 due to the loop. I know I had it similar in my code, but as @J A mentioned it was wrong. What I would like it to do is to save only one file (but with the right number suffix). +1 anyway for making it work to any point.

Answer (score 0):

adding the suffix onto the end of the filename will put it after the file extension.
The following will put your suffix before the dot. I am going to rewrite it to work with files with multiple dots.

```
$suffixed = explode('.', $fileName);
$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $upload_dir.$suffixed[0].$i.'.'.$suffixed[1]);
```

The following solution will work for files with a multiple amount of dots.

```
$moo  = explode('.', $fileName);
$ext  = array_pop($moo);
$fil  = implode('', $moo);
$moo  = $upload_dir . $fil . $i . '.' . $ext;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code it will work for all type of file type

```
$fileTmpLoc =  $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

$file_name=pathinfo($fileName,PATHINFO_FILENAME);           
$file_type=pathinfo($fileName,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$rand=rand(0,9999);                 
$filename=$file_name.$rand.".".$file_type;          
$upload_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/projektOpole/upload/";                  
move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, upload_dir.$fileName);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the result is the same - it saves the file in upload folder for the first time and after another upload attempt all I can see is one file, without any extensions.

Comment: no it is not possible to have same file name in the uploaded folder.